# vb.net checkbox invalid cast exception

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, radio-button, select-case

I don't like to admit it but I am building a vb.net winform that requires the use of reading text fields, check boxes or radio buttons to build a sql query and return results. the sql query part works fantastically however the select case statements don't seem to be evaluating the checkbox or radio checkstate correctly.

```
Select Case True
Case txtFirstName.Text.Length > 0 & chkActive.CheckState
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(txtFirstName.Text)
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtFirstName.Text.Length > 0 & chkActive.CheckState
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(txtFirstName.Text, , , "Active")
    chkInactive.Enabled = False
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtFirstName.Text.Length > 0 & chkInactive.CheckState
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(txtFirstName.Text, , , "Inactive")
    chkActive.Enabled = False
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtLastName.Text.Length > 0 & chkActive.CheckState
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(, txtLastName.Text)
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtLastName.Text.Length > 0 & chkActive.CheckState
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(, txtLastName.Text, , "Active")
    chkInactive.Enabled = False
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtLastName.Text.Length > 0 & chkInactive.CheckState
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(, txtLastName.Text, , "Inactive")
    chkActive.Enabled = False
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtEmpCode.Text.Length > 0 & rdbActive.Checked
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(, , txtEmpCode.Text)
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtEmpCode.Text.Length > 0 & chkActive.Checked
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(, , txtEmpCode.Text, "Active")
    chkInactive.Enabled = False
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case txtEmpCode.Text.Length > 0 & chkInactive.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = employess.FindEmployee(, , txtEmpCode.Text, "Inactive")
    chkActive.Enabled = False
    dgvEmployees.Visible = True
Case Else
    MessageBox.Show("please enter an employee code, firstname or lastname")
End Select
```

Every time I debug i get an invalid cast exception for the radio button or check box, am I missing something?

Comment: `&` is not the right thing to use.  `AndAlso` performs a logical `And`

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but, arent the tests for checks 1 and 2 identical?  Same with 3 and 4.  Since the text length tests is the same everywhere, that could be done once.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the help. I didn't know it followed a similar syntax as vb6. I was under the impression that it would follow C# syntax....as ignorant as that may sound.

Comment: @Plutonix no they use different parameter of another function because I have created a query can will search either textbox for a result...I have 3 different textboxes that build a single query to return a table result in data grid view....If you have a more efficient way to doing it I am open to suggestions....I normally write with C#

Comment: `Case txtFirstName.Text.Length > 0 & chkActive.CheckState` is the same test for #1 and #2.  The code for the second test is never going to run

Comment: @Plutonix Oh I didn't see that....thanks for pointing that out for me I will fix that. I appreciate the help

Comment: First off, set `Option Strict On`.  That way you would have never been able to compile that code and the IDE would have guided you to the problems.  You are also using a mix of  `Checked` and `CheckedState`.  Some usages are correct (other than the "&") and others are not.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks for the input. I will look at the options strict setting on my project and ensure that it is on. I assumed that it was already on and I hope it does help me in the long run so I don't have such trivial issues. I had those different type of usages because I was trying to figure out why it was working. Thanks for the help and advice tntinMn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Basic, `&` [performs a string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator). You want to use [`And`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator) or [`AndAlso`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator), as was mentioned by Plutonix.

`AndAlso` would be the better choice, as it skips evaluating the second condition if the first fails. For example, if `txtFirstName.Text` has a length of 0, the program would not bother to check the state of `chkActive.CheckState`. Actually, because of this, it might be theoretically a *tiny* bit more efficient to do check `chkActive.CheckState` first, because that is probably a little faster to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback nayrangnu. That is something will remember from now on. I appreciate the help. And thanks for the evaluation tip I will make that change.